# Airflow: How can I grab the dag_run.conf value in an ECSOperator

Tags: python, docker, aws-fargate, airflow

I have a process that uses Airflow to execute docker containers on AWS fargate. The docker containers are just running ETL's written in Python. In some of my python scripts I want to allow team members to pass commands and think dag_run.conf will be a good way to accomplish this. I was wondering if there was a way to append the values from dag_run.conf to the command key in the ecsoperator's override clause. My overrides clause looks something like this:

````
                "containerOverrides": [
                    {
                        "name": container_name,
                        "command": c.split(" ")
                    },
                ],```
````

Answer (score 0):

Pass in a JSON to `dag_run.conf` with a key `overrides` >> which will be passed into `EcsOperator` >>  which in turn will be [passed to the underlying boto3 client](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/5e7ad0b5133db6014b2996db8efd60664369c8cc/airflow/providers/amazon/aws/operators/ecs.py#L155) (during `run_task` operation).

To override container commands, add the key `containerOverrides` (to the `overrides` dict) whose [value is a list of dictionaries](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ecs.html#ECS.Client.run_task). **Note:** you must reference the specific container name.

An example input:

```json
{
    "overrides": {
        "containerOverrides": [
            {
                "name": "my-container-name",
                "command": ["echo", "hello world"]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Notes:

- Be sure to reference the exact container name
- Command should be a list of strings.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem and here's what I found:

- You cannot pass a command as string and then do `.split(" ")`. This is due to the fact that Airflow templating does *not* happen when the DAG is parsed. Instead, the literal `{{ dag_run.conf['command']}}`  (or, in my formulation, `{{ params.my_command }}`) is passed to the `EcsOperator` and only evaluated just before the task is run. So we need to keep the definition (yes, as string) `"{{ params.my_command }}"` in the code and pass it through.
- By default, all parameters for a DAG as passed as `string` types, but they don't have to! After playing around with [jsonschema](https://json-schema.org/) a bit, I found that you can express "list of strings" as a parameter type like this: `Param(type="array", items={"type": "string"})`.
- The above only ensures that the input can be a list of strings, but you also need to *receive* it as a list of strings. That functionality is simply switched on by setting `render_template_as_native_obj=True`.

All put together, you get something like this for your DAG:

```py
@dag(
    default_args={"owner": "airflow"},
    start_date=days_ago(2),
    schedule_interval=None,
    params={"my_command": Param(type="array", items={"type": "string"}, default=[])},
    render_template_as_native_obj=True,
)
def my_command():
    """run a command manually"""
    EcsOperator(
        task_id="my_command", 
        overrides={
            "containerOverrides": [
                {"name": "my-container-name", "command": command}
            ]
        },
        command="{{ params.my_command }}",
        ...
    )


dag = my_command()
```